# Can Covid19 Force Majeure be reason to lift my ban in Politics Stackexchange?

Tags: support, post-ban

I have politics question which is very important in Covid19 times (the question is - `are the politicians that invite people to participate in Phase 2/3 Covid19 vaccine trials and why there are so few such politicians? Note: inusfficient participation rates from the general public is the sole obstacle for completion of vaccine trials`) but I am banned from politics site. Yet - my question is very important in these times. Can Force Majeure argument be used to lift my ban, at least - to ask just this single question?

Answer (score 9):

No.

If that question were so important, someone else would ask it.

Also, you aren't "banned from Politics Stack Exchange". You were automatically blocked from asking questions because you asked too many questions in a short amount of time which were downvoted, closed and/or deleted. For more information on the automatic question block and how to get out of it, please read the article "[Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)" from the help center.

Comment: And, to be clear, no moderator or even staff member can remove such a block. The user must put in the effort to improve their content or their overall participation such that the block is removed by the system.

Comment: 2nd para *"If that question were so important, someone else would ask it."* is irrelevant, it's analogous to *"If God had meant man to fly, he'd have given him wings."*  A question's importance does not necessarily correlate with the number of askers.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like a bad Q.  Thus:

[Why so few politicians inviting the public to participate in Covid19 vaccine trials?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/57599/why-so-few-politicians-inviting-the-public-to-participate-in-covid19-vaccine-tri)

Please comment further as seems advisable...